# TYPO3 routeEnhancers with suffix '.html' on rootpage

Tags: typo3, url-routing, slug, typo3-9.x

Is there still no option to have the baseurl like 'www.mysite.com' if routeEnhancers are configured with '.html' suffix?

In my opinion this should be a basic feature but I can't find any solution. Redirecting the Homepage Link is not an option, as canonicals are still pointing to the wrong URL (www.mysite.com/index.html)

Is there any solution?

My configuration looks like this:

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: '.html'
    index: index
    map:
      .html: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The [reported issue on forge.typo3.org](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86585) is still open (as of September 2019).

For the time beeing, you can provide a **custom PageType decorator** which achieves the desired result. Daniel Dorndorf, the developer who reported the issue, kindly posted the source code for this:

#### /Classes/Routing/Enhancer/CustomPageTypeDecorator.php

```
<?php

namespace Brand\Extensionname\Classes\Routing\Enhancer;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Enhancer\PageTypeDecorator;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Class CustomPageTypeDecorator
 */
class CustomPageTypeDecorator extends PageTypeDecorator
{
    public const IGNORE_INDEX = [
        '/index.html',
        '/index/',
    ];

    public const ROUTE_PATH_DELIMITERS = ['.', '-', '_', '/'];

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\RouteCollection $collection
     * @param array $parameters
     */
    public function decorateForGeneration(RouteCollection $collection, array $parameters): void
    {
        parent::decorateForGeneration($collection, $parameters);

        /**
         * @var string $routeName
         * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Route $route
         */
        foreach ($collection->all() as $routeName => $route) {
            $path = $route->getPath();

            if (true === \in_array($path, self::IGNORE_INDEX, true)) {
                $route->setPath('/');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### ext_localconf.php

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

// Register custom PageTypeDecorator:
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['routing']['enhancers'] += ['CustomPageType' => \Brand\Extensionname\Classes\Routing\Enhancer\CustomPageTypeDecorator::class];
```

Add this to your template extension, adjust the PHP namespace (`\Brand\Extensionname\`) and you're done.

#### config.yaml

```
PageTypeSuffix:
  type: CustomPageType
  default: '.html'
  index: 'index'
  map:
    '.html': 0
```